# How can I insert/add and delete a string in a list through a function in C?

Tags: c, string, list, insert

It seems that my code isn't working because I cannot add any string to the list. It seems like the list remains empty. After every input of a string like "asd" or a single character, the message that appears every time is:

> List is empty

Also, I don't know if the 'delete' function could work, because the 'insert' function isn't working.

Here's my code(It is a bit long):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct listnode
{
char data[100];
listnode *nextPtr;
};
```

Here is my insert function. PS: I want to insert names so they can be alphabetically ordered.

```
void insert(struct listnode *strPtr, char value[])
{
struct listnode *previousPtr, *currentPtr, *newPtr;

newPtr=(listnode*)malloc(sizeof(listnode));
strcpy(newPtr->data,value);
newPtr->nextPtr=NULL;
previousPtr=NULL;
currentPtr=strPtr;
if(newPtr!=NULL)
{
    while(currentPtr!=NULL && strcmp(currentPtr->data,value)>0)
    {
        previousPtr=currentPtr;
        currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    if(previousPtr==NULL)
    {
        newPtr->nextPtr=strPtr;
        strPtr=newPtr;
    }
    else
      {
        previousPtr->nextPtr=newPtr;
        newPtr->nextPtr=currentPtr;
       }
     }else printf("%s was not inserted. Insuffiecient memory!",value);

       }
```

Here is my delete function

```
  const char *del(struct listnode* strPtr, char value[])
    {
   struct listnode *previousPtr, *currentPtr, *tempPtr;

  if(strcmp(value, strPtr->data)==0) /*if the first node shall be 
   deleted*/
{
  /*delete node*/
  tempPtr=strPtr;
  strPtr=strPtr->nextPtr;
  free(tempPtr);
  return value;
  }
  else
   {
    previousPtr=strPtr;
    currentPtr=strPtr->nextPtr;
    while(currentPtr!=NULL && strcmp(value, currentPtr->data)!=0)
    {
        previousPtr=currentPtr;
        currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;

    }

    if(currentPtr!=NULL)
    {
        tempPtr=currentPtr;
        previousPtr->nextPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
        free(tempPtr);
        return value;
    }
      }


    return '\0';//daca nu s-a gasit nodul

    }

    void instructions(void)
      {
    printf( "Options:\n"
     " 1 to insert a name in the list.\n"
     " 2 to delete a name from the list.\n"
     " 3 to exit.\n" );
     }

  void printList(struct listnode *currentPtr)
   {
      if(currentPtr==NULL)
        printf("List is empty\n");
        else
         {
    printf("List is:\n");
    while(currentPtr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s -->",currentPtr->data);
        currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
     }
  }
}

  int Empty(struct listnode *strPtr)
   {
     return strPtr == NULL;
    }

   int main()
      {
      struct listnode* startPtr;
       startPtr=NULL;

int optiune;
char nume[100];

instructions();
printf("->> ");
scanf("%d",&optiune);
```

Here is the menu

```
  while(optiune!=3)
  {
    switch(optiune)
    {
        case 1: 
            printf("Enter name:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(nume);
            insert(startPtr, nume);
            printList(startPtr);
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Search by name to delete from list:");
            gets(nume);
            if(!Empty(startPtr))
            {
                if(del(startPtr, nume))
                {
                    printf("%s a fost sters din lista!\n");
                    printList(startPtr);
                }else printf("%s nu a fost gasit!\n",nume);

            }else
                printf("List is empty!");
            break;

        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            printf("No such option!\n\n");
            instructions();
            break;
    }
    printf("\n->> ");
    scanf("%d",&optiune);
}
printf("Execution stopped.\n" );
return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: there is the same problem for del of course

Comment: What do you actually mean by "C is pass by refrence"? I'm sorry, I can't really understand, I'm a beginner. How should I write instead?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: `C is pass by reference` -- Except when it isn't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oops, that should have said "pass by value".  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Except when it isn't.  As you well know, you can get pass by value and pass by reference semantics in C, if you really want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it to work.

First thing I changed in your code was defining your struct as a typdef.

```
typedef struct{
   char data[100];
   struct listnode *nextPtr;
}listnode;
```

This is how I learned and it makes it easier to declare variables of this struct type, since we can just type "listnode" instead of "struct listnode" all the time.

Since you didn't give us the full code, I had to remove some things so I could compile it. As you are just asking why the list remains empty after the "insert" function I think this is fine for you.So here's the "main()" and "printlist()" functions that I used:

```
void printList(listnode *strPtr){
    listnode *currentPtr = malloc(sizeof(listnode));

    //Setting the ptr to run the list
    currentPtr = strPtr;
    if(strPtr == NULL) printf("Fail\n");

    //Printing the list,while next is different than NULL keep going
    printf("\nListing:\n");
    while(currentPtr->data != NULL){
       printf("%s\n",currentPtr->data);
       currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
   }
}

int main(){
   char nume[128];
   listnode *startPtr = NULL;//Initializing the fisrt ptr

   //Reading the name
   printf("Enter name:\n");
   scanf("%s",nume);

   //Inserting and printing the list
   insert(&startPtr,nume);
   insert(&startPtr,"Hello");
   printList(startPtr);

   return 0;   
 }
```

Some pretty basic stuff. Now to the main point:

As our friends told us in the comments, in C, the pointer is passed by value. It means that whatever changes you make in the function, it will not modify the startPtr variable in main().
To fix that all he have to do is to add one extra '*' on the function parameters. This means that we are now passing the strPtr argument by reference.

Here's the final function:

```
void insert(listnode **strPtr,char value[]){
    listnode *previousPtr, *currentPtr,*newPtr;

   //Allocating the nodes
   newPtr = malloc(sizeof(listnode));
   currentPtr = malloc(sizeof(listnode));

   //Initializing the new node and setting the currentPtr
   strcpy(newPtr->data,value);//Copying the name to the new node
   newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
   currentPtr = strPtr;

   //Previous is NULL
   previousPtr = NULL;

   if(newPtr != NULL){
       //If there's already a node in the list let's find the right location 
       //For the new one(sorting)
       while(currentPtr != NULL && strcmp(currentPtr->data,value) > 0){
           previousPtr = currentPtr;
           currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
       }

       //If previous is NULL than this is the first node,no while iterations
       //Note:strPtr is passed by reference,extra '*' needed
       if(previousPtr == NULL){
           newPtr->nextPtr = *strPtr;
           *strPtr = newPtr;
       }else{
           previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
           newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
           *strPtr = newPtr;
       }
   }else{ 
       printf("%s was not inserted. Insuffiecient memory!",value);
   }
}
```

Note that we are also using an extra '*' when setting the newPtr to strPtr.This will modify the actual variable startPtr from main().

From that I hope you can also fix the delete function! 
Don't forget to free the memory!
Also, don't forget to comment your code. It's really important to help you and other people to understand it, no matter how easy it might be!

Cheers!